# C# WebRequest TLS 1.2 (The request was aborted) only first time

Tags: c#, ssl, .net-4.0, tls1.2, webrequest

I have a strange problem. When i try to get response from WebRequest it always give me excpetion for first time

```
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

If i try second time and more then everything is OK.

Application is 4.0 .NET and uses TLS 1.2 like this:

```
 ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
 ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

Comment: TLS1.2 needs to use .NET 4.6 IIRC

Comment: Correction, seems like 4.5 is the base for support: https://blogs.perficient.com/2016/04/28/tsl-1-2-and-net-support/

Comment: @Jaxi you can use TLS1.2 even in 3.5 with the right service pack

Comment: I don't think the prblem is in installed framework, because it works if i try again. Problem is only first time.

Comment: I would try another known good endpoint (unrelated to the one experiencing the problem) to see if maybe it is the service you are connecting to that has the problem. Also a possibility is the hardware between your machine and the Internet. Things like Websense basically do a man-in-the-middle attack on traffic and it could be causing problems though that is not my area of expertise.